# Hot code swap is not working, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, hotswap

When I'm trying to write a simple one class console app - there is no problem. I can change code in a method when debugging.

The problem is with my web apps on Jetty. It's not working nor just in usual debug mode(pressing a debug button in eclipse) nor in remote debug mode described [here](http://clickonchris.com/2010/05/configuring-jetty-maven-and-eclipse-together-with-hot-deploy/). I can debug but can't change even usual not static methods, like adding sysout for example, I mean I can change it but after saving it's not updated and it works the same as before.

Also, I talked to my colleagues, it works for them but they use Spring Tool Suite version of eclipse, I tried and concluded that it works in the latest version STS out of the box in usual debug mode and it doesn't work in the latest version of Eclipse.

What can be a reason?

Comment: Is your `Build Automatically` option turned on?

Comment: Have you upgraded your Eclipse lately? Happened to me once, that I've upgraded and re-used old workspace with old `.metadata` and the debugger behaved quite randomly. **Try to run the project in a fresh clean workspace!**

Comment: @Pavel Horal That particular thing didn't work, but It made me try to remake eclipse files using maven plugin "mvn eclipse:clean" - "mvn eclipse:eclipse" and it worked. Thanks, you can write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Maven Eclipse Plugin (`mvn eclipse:*`) is obsolete... I suggest you to switch to **m2e** (which is Eclipse plugin and not Maven plugin). It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer based on my comments to the question (as suggested by OP):

Strange Eclipse behaviour can happen when your workspace or project metadata are corrupted. This can happen for example when you upgrade Eclipse version and use workspace created by the old version.

**You should try to re-create your workspace and setup fresh project checkout.** If the problem goes away, you know there was something fishy in the workspace metadata.

Comment: You are basically making the generic reply "If its broken it won't work". You have no proof that this is the case here, so this is not an actual answer.

Comment: @Gimby I wrote this answer based on my comments and suggestion from OP. Please remove the downvote. Thank you.

Comment: I have given you suffient reason why I downvote, if someone else does not agree with me they are free to upvote it again. Your answer is not an answer.

Comment: OP had a problem with hot swap, which should work. Eclipse does not behave correctly when metadata is corrupted. OP said, that recreating the project helped. So I don't see how this is not a correct answer, even that I am not able to pinpoint the exact cause. At least I am not suggesting commercial product to just solve a configuration problem ;).

Comment: I didn't create another workspace though, I just ran "mvn eclipse:clean" - "mvn eclipse:eclipse"

Comment: @MaxNevermind I understand. That deletes and re-creates `.settings` and `.project`. I still consider that as a *metadata corruption* as a cause. But if anyone else have similar problems, re-creating project might not be sufficient (in your case it was). It happened to me more than once that I've messed up workspace `.metadata`.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use hot swap proxy for swapping classes in EE container like **[jRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/display/?utm_source=google-c&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=jrebel-dl&gclid=CLn4su3Y7rwCFWT4wgodjKEAsQ)**.
Check it out.

Comment: You don't need jRebel for *Hot Swap*. The fact that an application is running on server is irrelevant.

Comment: @PavelHoral It was never irrelevant to me when I was working as Java EE developer for JBoss... Are you sure we are talking about the same thing? `Hot Swap != Hot Redeploy`

Comment: It's not free, is it? This is out of the box feature that should work, I'd prefer at first try to work with it

Comment: Yes, it is not free. There are (or is) some free alternatives, however we had some troubles using it at work, and we stayed with jRebel. You surely cat evaluate it, if you want though.

Comment: HotSwap is a JVM feature. Hot Redeploy is a application server feature. JRebel goes beyond hotswap for JVM part and beyond redeploys for app server part.

Comment: You are right, nevertheless we needed it. Why don't you post another answer explaining how to achieve that using JVM feature? I bet OP would be gratefull.

Comment: JVM debugger feature to be more exact. It doesn't work if you don't start the JVM in debug mode (which in the context of eclipse means starting the JEE container in debug mode).

Comment: @GimbyI tried running app ussing -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n Should that have worked?

Comment: ay, something like that. Can you even debug your code and hot swap is not working, or you can't debug at all?

Comment: I can debug but can't change even usual not static methods, I mean I can change it but after saving it's not updated and it works the same as before

Comment: @AntonArhipov Can you elaborate on comment above?

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, I am pretty sure. If the application is Java and is running in DEBUG, you can use *HotSwap*. EE or not. You need tools like jRebel if you want to have advanced features like class reloading. But OP was specifically asking about hot-swap. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html