# Breakpoint not registered in eclipse in maven multi-module web application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging, tomcat

I'm currently working with a maven multi-module application in eclipse.

In some classes I can set breakpoints, and after starting tomcat (via eclipse) in debug mode, they get registered (meaning, a small tick icon is displayed next to the blue round breakpoint icon), and the debugger stops there.

In some other classes, the breakpoint is not registered, and the debugger doesn't stop there.

Why? And what's the mechanism underneath, like, are breakpoints only registered for classes that were already loaded? Or how does that work?

Update: 
Using Eclipse 4.5.2 under Linux, Tomcat started under Oracle Java 1.6.0_45

Comment: I had similar issue when i had too many break points when I remove all and added new one it worked

Comment: I have five, so that should not be the issue, but what you say indicates that it can also be an eclipse problem - thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to provide answer for such generic issue... however here are some hints. Let's assume the structure of your multi-module is following:

- *foo-project* (parent, POM packaging)

  - *foo-library* (JAR packaging)
  - *foo-webapp* (WAR packaging, depends on *foo-library*)

Now from Eclipse's point of view, you have 3 "separate" projects. You are running your *foo-webapp* on Tomcat and that is what you are debugging. If you place breakpoint inside *foo-library* that is a different project, potentially unconnected to *foo-webapp*.

So what you need to do is to make sure your *foo-webapp* has **project dependency** on *foo-library* so that Eclipse knows when you run one project, the other is used as well. This is usually **done manually automatically** but by the **m2e** plugin. So I hope you are using that and not the obsolete *maven-eclipse-plugin*. Next thing you should make sure is that your dependency is correctly defined in the pom.xml... if the required version is not the same as the version of the library, m2e might link you JAR and not the project itself. And last not least you need to *Enable Workspace Resolution* for m2e to actually start connecting projects.

[image: Workspace resolution]

If you are sure all the things above are correct in your case, you might try to update the project according to the POM via *Right click on project > Maven > Update Project...*.

When everything is in place you should see your project dependencies under Maven Dependencies in your *Java Build Path* tab.

[image: Project dependencies]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm using m2e (comes with eclipse 4.5.2 already), workspace resolution is enabled, the projects where I have the Java classes with my not registered breakpoints are displayed both in the Java Build Path, as well as in the Deployment Assembly, and in both views with a Eclipse Project Icon (and not with a Jar icon). Setup is almost as you described, only that the foo-project only has an aggregating pom (hence is not the parent of the sub modules).

Comment: Also the referenced versions are the same everywhere (otherwise the referenenced projects would be displayed with a jar icon, not with a project icon). The strange thing is that in some other modules where the war has a dependency on, breakpoints are registered and respected. On my colleagues' pcs, the breakpoints work everywhere (hence it's not a problem with our pom setup)

Comment: Already did several clean and update project configuration cycles, didn't help unfortunately

Comment: No I don't mean project clean and update. I mean literally do create a new workspace. I have seen corrupted `.metadata` few times where one of the symptoms was buggy debugger. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093583/hot-code-swap-is-not-working-why/22143681#22143681

Comment: I just started with a fresh workspace from scratch - that didn't help either.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas... sorry :(... will leave the answer here as it might help someone else.